# Can I use one single TypeConverter for different object types?

Tags: android, database, android-room, android-architecture-components

So far for storing in **Room Database** I've been using type converter for each classes. Like this:

```
@SerializedName("sidebar")
@Expose
@TypeConverters(SidebarConverter.class)
private Sidebar sidebar;
@SerializedName("splash")
@Expose
@TypeConverters(SplashConverter.class)
private Splash splash;
@SerializedName("overview")
@Expose
@TypeConverters(OverviewConverter.class)
private Overview overview;
@SerializedName("home")
@Expose
@TypeConverters(HomeConverter.class)
private Home home;
@SerializedName("portfolio")
@Expose
@TypeConverters(PortfolioConverter.class)
private Portfolio portfolio;
@SerializedName("team")
@Expose
@TypeConverters(TeamConverter.class)
private Team team;
```

I want to know if there's a more convenient way to use one `TypeConverter` single handedly in Database.

Answer (score 6):

You can define all your converter in a Single Class like this:

```
public class DateTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static Date toDate(Long value) {
        return value == null ? null : new Date(value);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long toLong(Date value) {
        return value == null ? null : value.getTime();
    }
}
```

And then set this converter on your Room Database with `@TypeConverter` annotation like this which work globally on any `@Entity` class.You don't need to define `@TypeConverter` Individually in Entity class

```
@Database(entities = {Product.class}, version = 1)
@TypeConverters({DateTypeConverter.class})
public abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract ProductDao productDao();
}
```

Note we’ve added a new annotation named `@TypeConverters` in our database definition in order to reference the different converters that we can have (you can separate it by commas and add others).

Comment: But there will be different methods for each different classes. What you are saying is making a class and copy paste all other `@TypeConverters` codes for different classes into that specific class?

Comment: Either you can put all that in Single Class or if you already have multiple classes for multiple converter you can reference the different converters by comma seperated in `@TypeConverters({SidebarConverter.class,SplashConverter.class,PortfolioConverter.class})`

Comment: So still it's a lot of repeated code. There's no generic way then?

Comment: Nop there is no generic way as of now.But this approach has less boilerplate code than your current implementation.Its defining your converters globally instead of on each object in Entity class

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid - this syntax to add more than one TypeConverter does not compile for me.  When I add them as @TypeConverters(TimeConverters::class, EventConverters::class) -- it compiles, but runtime crashes.  I think I can only have one class file and I have to combine the code into one class -- which can be a problem for modularizing, maintenance, etc. -- Any thoughts??  [note, i am reading your 2018 post, in the far future of 2023 :) ]

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that Room's code generation tries to find specific type, and if you try to make a generic converter it fails to generate appropriate methods.
However, if in your case it's appropriate to transfrom data to json for storage, you can reduce boilerplate like this:

```
@TypeConverter
fun toSomething(value: String): Something = fromJson(value)

@TypeConverter
fun fromSomething(value: Something): String = toJson(value)
```

fromJson and toJson are generic, for example they can look like this. Any time you need to add types, just take two methods above and replace 'Something' with your type. If you have a lot of classes to convert, you can even code-gen TypeConverters like this pretty easily to satisfy Room's code-gen needs.

```
inline fun <reified T> fromJson(value: String): T {
    val jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(T::class.java)
    return jsonAdapter.fromJson(value)
}

inline fun <reified T> toJson(value: T): String {
    val jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(T::class.java)
    return jsonAdapter.toJson(value)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work with room. Error: `e: /Users/adamhurwitz/Code/CryptoTweets/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/app/cryptotweets/feed/models/entities/Entities.java:8: error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.`