# Android Room type convert multiple enum types

Tags: enums, kotlin, android-room

I am writing a type converter for my Room database. I have a couple custom enum classes and I want to convert all of them to its ordinals when stored in the database. So, instead of writing the following for every single class, is there any way to simplify it (such as pass in a generic enum type)?

```
class Converter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun toOrdinal(type: TypeA): Int = type.ordinal

    @TypeConverter
    fun toTypeA(ordinal: Int): TypeA = TypeA.values().first { it.ordinal == ordinal }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toOrdinal(type: TypeB): Int = type.ordinal

    @TypeConverter
    fun toTypeB(ordinal: Int): TypeB = TypeB.values().first { it.ordinal == ordinal }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Is `TypeA` and `TypeB` 2 different enum classes or part of single enum?

Comment: different enum classes

Comment: I guess it's not possible to create multiple type converters in one convert class for 2 enum classes. Since you have 2 `TypeA` and `TypeB` you should create another converter specific to `TypeB`. Alternatively, if both  are similar in structure you can use a parent `interface` and make `TypeA` and `TypeB` inherit that interface and write a converter for that interface that would either convert to/from the object to `TypeA` and `TypeB`

Comment: I see, do you mind show me how to write such an interface? Say all types have the form `enum class TypeA(val abbrv: String)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49398023/4465208), Room can't handle generic converters at the moment. I think the best you can do is create extensions that make writing these enum converters quicker:

```
@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
private inline fun <T : Enum<T>> T.toInt(): Int = this.ordinal

private inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> Int.toEnum(): T = enumValues<T>()[this]
```

This would simplify each pair of converters to this code:

```
@TypeConverter fun myEnumToTnt(value: MyEnum) = value.toInt()
@TypeConverter fun intToMyEnum(value: Int) = value.toEnum<MyEnum>()
```

Or if you might be storing null values:

```
@TypeConverter fun myEnumToTnt(value: MyEnum?) = value?.toInt()
@TypeConverter fun intToMyEnum(value: Int?) = value?.toEnum<MyEnum>()
```

Comment: Actually, yours doesn't work. Probably something wrong with your extension?

Comment: Can you say how specifically it's not working for you?

Comment: Room [2.3.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.3.0) from April 2021 supports Enums directly, so the type converters using the ordinal are no longer needed. (The latest stable Room at this time is 2.5.0).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a composition interface to achieve this as you cannot write a single converter class for multiple object types. It is kind of hacky but might just work:

```
interface BaseType {
    val arg0: String

    fun asString() : String? {
        return when(this) {
            is TypeA -> "${TypeA::class.simpleName}$separatorParam$arg0"
            is TypeB -> "${TypeB::class.simpleName}$separatorParam$arg0"
            else -> null
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val separatorParam = "::"
    }
}

enum class TypeA (override val arg0: String) : BaseType {
    A_ONE("argument 1"),
    A_TWO("argument 2");

    companion object {
        fun getValueTypes(arg0: String) : TypeA? = values().firstOrNull { it.arg0 == arg0 }
    }
}

enum class TypeB (override val arg0: String) : BaseType {
    A_ONE("argument 1"),
    A_TWO("argument 2");

    companion object {
        fun getValueTypes(arg0: String) : TypeB? = values().firstOrNull { it.arg0 == arg0 }
    }
}

class Converter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromBaseType(type: BaseType) : String? = type.asString()

    @TypeConverter
    fun toBaseType(param: String?) : BaseType? = param?.asBaseType()

    private fun String.asBaseType() : BaseType? {
        val stringArray = this.split(BaseType.separatorParam)
        val className : String? = stringArray[0]
        return when(className) {
            TypeA::class.simpleName -> TypeA.getValueTypes(stringArray[1])
            TypeB::class.simpleName -> TypeB.getValueTypes(stringArray[1])
            else -> null
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need a function in your `data class` to provide you the actual TypeA or TypeB

```
data class MyDbModel(val baseType: BaseType) {
    inline fun <reified T: BaseType> getTypeAs() : T? = 
            when(baseType) {
                is TypeA -> TypeA.getValueTypes(baseType.arg0) as? T
                is TypeB -> TypeB.getValueTypes(baseType.arg0) as? T
                else -> null
            }
}

fun foo() {
    val model = MyDbModel(TypeA.A_ONE)
    val type = model.getTypeAs<TypeA>()
}
```

The disadvantage of this is that it works only for unique `arg0` within the specific enum, for that you could use ordinal or you could use generated ID like `R.id.a_one` as the first parameter and then the second parameter could be your string.

Answer (score 0):

Just for historical reasons, it's worth noting that Room [2.3.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.3.0) released in April 2021 supports Enum types directly:

> **Built-in Enum Support**: Room will now default to using an Enum to String and vice versa type converter if none is provided. If a type converter for an enum already exists, Room will prioritize using it over the default one.

The latest Room (as of January 2023) is 2.5.0, which also supports AutoMigrations (actually introduced in 2.4.0):

> **Auto Migrations**: Room now offers an API for automatically generating migrations as long as schemas are exported.

Alas, this doesn't *auto-migrate* your INTEGER columns to TEXT. So to get "rid" of your old columns with the type converters, you'd need to (untested by me):

1. Create a New temporal table with new TEXT fields (instead of INTEGER).
2. Copy all the data from Old Table to New Table, except for the old fields with the enum ordinal values.
3. Perform an UPDATE on the NEW table to match each ordinal to its actual ENUM text value.
4. Drop the old table.
5. Rename the new table back to Old name.
6. Remove the Type Converters (probably before step 1?) Not sure if Room will complain or what actually happens as I haven't tried this.